# leaflet in windows 8 rt ajavascript app freezes on zoom

Tags: windows-runtime, winjs, leaflet

I have created a Windows Store app using JavaScript / HTML5 targeting Windows 8.1. The app has a leaflet 0.7.2 map on 3 pages in my single page application. I have the same application which runs great in the browser. The WinRT app also works great while debugging. The problem **only occurs when I'm not debugging**, then the maps starts freezing on zoom. When I use the app slowly, the map hardly ever freezes, but when I zoom 5- 10 times quickly in a row, the map freezes and only starts being responsive after I navigate to another page and then back to the map page.

I tried the following and these things are still active in my app:

- set a timeout around my zoomanimation and loadtile function
- set zoomanimation and fadeanimation to true
- I set unloadinvisibletiles to true

I turned on WinJS logging and i set WinJS.Application.onerror to log if an error occurs. But no errors or exceptions get thrown whatsever.

Does anyone know what I can do do solve this nasty bug?

Thanks in advance,

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a bug report which includes a workaround that works!

See here: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2693

Specifically, you need to add a bit of code:

```
map.on('zoomanim', debounce(map._onZoomTransitionEnd, 250));
```

The debounce function can be found here: http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: That was indeed my bug report.

Comment: That's funny! I am glad I ran across the bug report because I too was facing the problem.